# Python Scraping - Unable to get required data from Flipkart

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape the customer reviews from Flipkart website. The following is the [link](https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j5-6-new-2016-edition-white-16-gb/product-reviews/itmegmrnzqjcpfg9?pid=MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z). The following was my code to scrape, but it is always returning an empty list.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests

>>> r = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j5-6-new-2016-edition-white-16-gb/product-reviews/itmegmrnzqjcpfg9?pid=MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml') # Tried with 'html.parser' also
>>> soup.find_all('div', '_3DCdKt')
[]
>>> soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_3DCdKt'})
[]
>>> soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'row _3wYu6I _3BRC7L'})
[]
>>> soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_1GRhLX hFPo14'})
[]
```

So, I tried to get the entire section, but I was getting only the following:

```
>>> soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-9-12'})
[<div class="col-9-12" data-reactid="96"><div class="row _2_xtR5" data-reactid="97"></div><div class="row _3wYu6I _1KVtzT" data-reactid="98"></div></div>]
```

I was not getting the other contents. So, next I tried with selenium, even then it was returning `None`. The following is my selenium code:

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j5-6-new-2016-edition-white-16-gb/product-reviews/itmegmrnzqjcpfg9?pid=MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z')
>>> a = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_3DCdKt")
>>> len(a)
10
>>> for i in a:
...    print i.get_attribute('value')
...
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

What might be the problem? Am I doing any mistakes in the code. Kindly help. I am new to Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reviews etc.. are populated using *reactjs*, the data is retrieved using an ajax request which you can mimic with requests:

```
import requests

data = {"productId": "MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z", # end of url pid=MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z
        "count": "15",
        "ratings": "ALL",
        "reviewerType:ALL"
        "sortOrder": "MOST_HELPFUL"}



headers = ({"x-user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36 FKUA/website/41/website/Desktop"})
data = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/api/3/product/reviews", params=data, headers=headers).json()
print(data)
```

What you want is to access `data["RESPONSE"]["data"]` which is a list of dicts:

```
for dct in data["RESPONSE"]["data"]
    print(dct)
```

Which will give you:

```
{u'action': None, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'rating': 5, u'text': u'Thanks to Flipkart who deliver it me with in 5 days \nGood Phone With Metal Body \nAnd Best front Camera With Flash\nBest for night Selfie \nI Take more than 30 pic in night mode with front flash \ngood smartphone  gold color is also supereb\nbest ever smartphone under 15k by samsung\nGood Battery\nGood Camera Front with Flash and Rear Also Superb', u'reportAbuse': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'ABUSE', u'reviewId': u'be37810e-20fe-4417-9d88-2709288cf2ba', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'totalCount': 285, u'downvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'DOWN', u'reviewId': u'be37810e-20fe-4417-9d88-2709288cf2ba', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 74, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'id': u'be37810e-20fe-4417-9d88-2709288cf2ba', u'author': u'Happy Thakur', u'url': u'/reviews/be37810e-20fe-4417-9d88-2709288cf2ba', u'upvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'UP', u'reviewId': u'be37810e-20fe-4417-9d88-2709288cf2ba', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 211, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'helpfulCount': 211, u'created': u'16 May, 2016', u'certifiedBuyer': True, u'title': u'Best Smartphone by Samsung', u'type': u'ProductReviewValue'}, u'tracking': None}
{u'action': None, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'rating': 5, u'text': u"Updated Review on 02-August after 3 months of usage:\nWhat I liked most:\nLook : 100/100 - Very good looking phone. Gold color and the finishing is super cool\nSize : 100/100 - 5.2 Inch is neither big nor small. I can still operate with one hand.. \nBattery : 100/100 - 3100 mAH is outstanding. 3G is always ON when i am out of home and Wi-Fi is always ON in home. I am charging mobile only once in every 36 hours. I use Whatsapp, instagram and Browsing mostly. \nDisplay : 90/100 - Not so bright and sharp as S series phones, but a real deal for the price. Impressed again. My only worry is about it is not having a Gorilla scratch proof glass. I may need to use tempered glass.\nTouch : 95/100 - So smooth and I dont see any lags as of now.\nCamera : 90/100 - Photos are good and can capture fast, but again not as great as S series phones. but at this price I believe this phone outclasses all other competitors in camera department. \n\nOne last thing is about the SAMSUNG brand and its service center coverage, which is again awesome. \nOverall I am completely satisfied with the phone and this phone reached my expectations. \nWhat I disliked:\nEarphone jack at the bottom.. I feel uncomfortable when chatting and listening to songs at same time\nLow speaker volume, not a big deal though for me, As i don't use loudspeaker for songs mostly", u'reportAbuse': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'ABUSE', u'reviewId': u'e786669a-024b-4ef0-b70c-1e4fcf5fe5ff', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'totalCount': 272, u'downvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'DOWN', u'reviewId': u'e786669a-024b-4ef0-b70c-1e4fcf5fe5ff', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 87, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'id': u'e786669a-024b-4ef0-b70c-1e4fcf5fe5ff', u'author': u'Naresh Kareti', u'url': u'/reviews/e786669a-024b-4ef0-b70c-1e4fcf5fe5ff', u'upvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'UP', u'reviewId': u'e786669a-024b-4ef0-b70c-1e4fcf5fe5ff', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 185, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'helpfulCount': 185, u'created': u'13 May, 2016', u'certifiedBuyer': True, u'title': u'Absolute Stunner and Impressive', u'type': u'ProductReviewValue'}, u'tracking': None}
{u'action': None, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'rating': 3, u'text': u'Hi,\n\nI got this phone from Flipkart on Friday and here is my 3 days review.\n\nPros:\n * Beautiful design\n * Very handy, easy to handle\n * Battery backup is great\n * Back camera is good\n * No heating issues\n \nCons:\n * If we are charging, it will not show any light or any notification whether it is charging or not. We need to on the screen and check whether it is charging or not. So every time we need to turn it on and see whether it is charging or not.\n* Camera issue: Once you take the picture and then press the back button it is taking some time to come back to camera mode.\n* If you turn on the flash and take pic with back camera it is taking some time to capture the picture. With out Flash it is taking very fast.\n* Volume is very low. Not enough for a medium sized room.\n* Ear phones are not good especially for me. \n\n\nWill post my feedback after using it another 15 days.\n\nThanks', u'reportAbuse': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'ABUSE', u'reviewId': u'9cbcd27c-a8ad-4793-978a-5903cd086252', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'totalCount': 212, u'downvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'DOWN', u'reviewId': u'9cbcd27c-a8ad-4793-978a-5903cd086252', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 67, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'id': u'9cbcd27c-a8ad-4793-978a-5903cd086252', u'author': u'ileep ', u'url': u'/reviews/9cbcd27c-a8ad-4793-978a-5903cd086252', u'upvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'UP', u'reviewId': u'9cbcd27c-a8ad-4793-978a-5903cd086252', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 145, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'helpfulCount': 145, u'created': u'16 May, 2016', u'certifiedBuyer': True, u'title': u'Good looking phone with some drawbacks', u'type': u'ProductReviewValue'}, u'tracking': None}
{u'action': None, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'rating': 5, u'text': u'Super Amoled Display..2 GB RAM with Latest Android Marshmallow OS only for 13K....its difficult to get Samsung Phone with 2 GB ram in such a low price Range...used for 15 days....Going Smooth....Awesome Earphone Quality.....selfie and back Camera Good.....Battery last for more than a day with Continous usage or will go for two days....Free Microsoft apps and Much More...', u'reportAbuse': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'ABUSE', u'reviewId': u'1546ed16-5945-4257-9f2d-0d86db7ed92e', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'totalCount': 34, u'downvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'DOWN', u'reviewId': u'1546ed16-5945-4257-9f2d-0d86db7ed92e', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 9, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'id': u'1546ed16-5945-4257-9f2d-0d86db7ed92e', u'author': u'Prashant Dias', u'url': u'/reviews/1546ed16-5945-4257-9f2d-0d86db7ed92e', u'upvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'UP', u'reviewId': u'1546ed16-5945-4257-9f2d-0d86db7ed92e', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 25, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'helpfulCount': 25, u'created': u'7 Sep, 2016', u'certifiedBuyer': True, u'title': u'Brilliant Phone Compared to Money', u'type': u'ProductReviewValue'}, u'tracking': None}
{u'action': None, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'rating': 5, u'text': u"Nice.battery backup it's good", u'reportAbuse': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'ABUSE', u'reviewId': u'a9f2f6a0-2272-4187-bd37-48eb8a0a85c9', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'totalCount': 5, u'downvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'DOWN', u'reviewId': u'a9f2f6a0-2272-4187-bd37-48eb8a0a85c9', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'id': u'a9f2f6a0-2272-4187-bd37-48eb8a0a85c9', u'author': u'Flipkart Customer', u'url': u'/reviews/a9f2f6a0-2272-4187-bd37-48eb8a0a85c9', u'upvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'UP', u'reviewId': u'a9f2f6a0-2272-4187-bd37-48eb8a0a85c9', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 5, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'helpfulCount': 5, u'created': u'17 Aug, 2016', u'certifiedBuyer': True, u'title': u"It's very good", u'type': u'ProductReviewValue'}, u'tracking': None}
{u'action': None, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'rating': 5, u'text': u'This Phone is awesome..Must Buy', u'reportAbuse': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'ABUSE', u'reviewId': u'cf8cf2c8-1f79-4d56-a4cd-e641ffb3551b', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'totalCount': 5, u'downvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'DOWN', u'reviewId': u'cf8cf2c8-1f79-4d56-a4cd-e641ffb3551b', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'id': u'cf8cf2c8-1f79-4d56-a4cd-e641ffb3551b', u'author': u'Durvank Aregekar', u'url': u'/reviews/cf8cf2c8-1f79-4d56-a4cd-e641ffb3551b', u'upvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'UP', u'reviewId': u'cf8cf2c8-1f79-4d56-a4cd-e641ffb3551b', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 5, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'helpfulCount': 5, u'created': u'10 Aug, 2016', u'certifiedBuyer': True, u'title': u'Must Buy', u'type': u'ProductReviewValue'}, u'tracking': None}
{u'action': None, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'rating': 5, u'text': u'It is a good phone', u'reportAbuse': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'ABUSE', u'reviewId': u'ce31beb5-5c8f-4a2d-be7d-aba416592df2', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'totalCount': 5, u'downvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'DOWN', u'reviewId': u'ce31beb5-5c8f-4a2d-be7d-aba416592df2', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'id': u'ce31beb5-5c8f-4a2d-be7d-aba416592df2', u'author': u'Sourabh Jain', u'url': u'/reviews/ce31beb5-5c8f-4a2d-be7d-aba416592df2', u'upvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'UP', u'reviewId': u'ce31beb5-5c8f-4a2d-be7d-aba416592df2', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 5, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'helpfulCount': 5, u'created': u'9 Aug, 2016', u'certifiedBuyer': True, u'title': u'Good phone', u'type': u'ProductReviewValue'}, u'tracking': None}
{u'action': None, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'rating': 5, u'text': u'delivery is in time but my phone is heat will data is on plz check', u'reportAbuse': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'ABUSE', u'reviewId': u'1fcf5a13-edef-4b16-8372-8732819c143c', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'totalCount': 9, u'downvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'DOWN', u'reviewId': u'1fcf5a13-edef-4b16-8372-8732819c143c', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 1, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'id': u'1fcf5a13-edef-4b16-8372-8732819c143c', u'author': u'Santhoaha m n santhu', u'url': u'/reviews/1fcf5a13-edef-4b16-8372-8732819c143c', u'upvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'UP', u'reviewId': u'1fcf5a13-edef-4b16-8372-8732819c143c', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 8, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'helpfulCount': 8, u'created': u'12 Aug, 2016', u'certifiedBuyer': True, u'title': u'very good', u'type': u'ProductReviewValue'}, u'tracking': None}
{u'action': None, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'rating': 4, u'text': u'Good Product by Samsung\n\nThe things from this phone is\n       1. Marshmellow v6.0\n       2. Front flash with 5mb camera not so good\n       3. Its design\n       4. Primary Camera is not so good with 13mb led flash\n       5. Battery life is also not so good\n       6. Its size is correct in its design\n       7. Supports OTG\n       9. Only 2GB RAM\n      10. 16GB Internal storage but only 11GB is availiable\n      11. 4G supports\n      12. Ultra power saving mode\n      13. S bike mode\n      14. Speaker volume is not so good\n      15. 3G supports\n      16. Ultra data saving\n      17. No auto brightness\n      18. 2G supports\n      19. Top performance \n      20. Good phone at the price 14000\n      *********************', u'reportAbuse': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'ABUSE', u'reviewId': u'958efa75-1b67-4872-9f71-b18035fafe6a', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'totalCount': 20, u'downvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'DOWN', u'reviewId': u'958efa75-1b67-4872-9f71-b18035fafe6a', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 5, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'id': u'958efa75-1b67-4872-9f71-b18035fafe6a', u'author': u'Vaishnav ', u'url': u'/reviews/958efa75-1b67-4872-9f71-b18035fafe6a', u'upvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'UP', u'reviewId': u'958efa75-1b67-4872-9f71-b18035fafe6a', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 15, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'helpfulCount': 15, u'created': u'17 May, 2016', u'certifiedBuyer': True, u'title': u'By Expert     -Vaishnav VJ', u'type': u'ProductReviewValue'}, u'tracking': None}
{u'action': None, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'rating': 4, u'text': u'Very nice device', u'reportAbuse': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'ABUSE', u'reviewId': u'c7177dfb-39c2-4c0b-8bbd-288f96757c3a', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'totalCount': 4, u'downvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'DOWN', u'reviewId': u'c7177dfb-39c2-4c0b-8bbd-288f96757c3a', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 0, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'id': u'c7177dfb-39c2-4c0b-8bbd-288f96757c3a', u'author': u'Flipkart Customer', u'url': u'/reviews/c7177dfb-39c2-4c0b-8bbd-288f96757c3a', u'upvote': {u'action': {u'originalUrl': None, u'params': {u'vote': u'UP', u'reviewId': u'c7177dfb-39c2-4c0b-8bbd-288f96757c3a', u'reviewDomain': u'PRODUCT'}, u'loginType': u'LEGACY_LOGIN', u'url': None, u'fallback': None, u'type': u'REVIEW_VOTE', u'omnitureData': None, u'screenType': None, u'tracking': {}}, u'fixed': False, u'value': {u'count': 4, u'type': u'VoteValue'}, u'tracking': None}, u'helpfulCount': 4, u'created': u'8 Sep, 2016', u'certifiedBuyer': True, u'title': u'Good quality product', u'type': u'ProductReviewValue'}, u'tracking': None}
```

The `x-user-agent` is required, without it you will get a 403.  You can play around with the parameters to see different results, I will leave that up to you.

Comment: I tried changing the page, I gave the parameter `"page": "2"` in the data, but I was getting the same information as I got before. I tried to get the path URL using `data.request.path_url` and I pasted the url in the browser but it is returning an error. Could you please help me out with getting the reviews from other pages?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j5-6-new-2016-edition-white-16-gb/product-reviews/itmegmrnzqjcpfg9?pid=MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for entry in soup.find_all('div', '_3DCdKt'):
    print(entry.text)
```

Perhaps change `entry.text` to just `entry`, depending on your needs.

Output was:

```
5★Best Smartphone by SamsungThanks to Flipkart who deliver it me with in 5 days Good Phone With Metal Body And Best front Camera With FlashBest for night Selfie I Take more than 30 pic in night mode with front flash good smartphone  gold color is also superebbest ever smartphone under 15k by samsungGood BatteryGood Camera Front with Flash and Rear Also SuperbREAD MOREHappy ThakurCertified Buyer16 May, 201621776PermalinkReport Abuse
5★Must BuyThis Phone is awesome..Must BuyREAD MOREDurvank AregekarCertified Buyer10 Aug, 201680PermalinkReport Abuse
3★Good looking phone with some drawbacksHi,I got this phone from Flipkart on Friday and here is my 3 days review.Pros: * Beautiful design * Very handy, easy to handle * Battery backup is great * Back camera is good * No heating issues Cons: * If we are charging, it will not show any light or any notification whether it is charging or not. We need to on the screen and check whether it is charging or not. So every time we need to turn it on and see whether it is charging or not.* Camera issue: Once you take the picture a...READ MOREileep Certified Buyer16 May, 201615167PermalinkReport Abuse
5★Absolute Stunner and ImpressiveUpdated Review on 02-August after 3 months of usage:What I liked most:Look : 100/100 - Very good looking phone. Gold color and the finishing is super coolSize : 100/100 - 5.2 Inch is neither big nor small. I can still operate with one hand.. Battery : 100/100 - 3100 mAH is outstanding. 3G is always ON when i am out of home and Wi-Fi is always ON in home. I am charging mobile only once in every 36 hours. I use Whatsapp, instagram and Browsing mostly. Display : 90/100 - Not so bright and s...READ MORENaresh KaretiCertified Buyer13 May, 201618787PermalinkReport Abuse
5★It's very goodNice.battery backup it's goodREAD MOREFlipkart CustomerCertified Buyer17 Aug, 201660PermalinkReport Abuse
5★Good phoneIt is a good phoneREAD MORESourabh JainCertified Buyer9 Aug, 201660PermalinkReport Abuse
5★Brilliant Phone Compared to MoneySuper Amoled Display..2 GB RAM with Latest Android Marshmallow OS only for 13K....its difficult to get Samsung Phone with 2 GB ram in such a low price Range...used for 15 days....Going Smooth....Awesome Earphone Quality.....selfie and back Camera Good.....Battery last for more than a day with Continous usage or will go for two days....Free Microsoft apps and Much More...READ MOREPrashant DiasCertified Buyer7 Sep, 2016269PermalinkReport Abuse
5★very gooddelivery is in time but my phone is heat will data is on plz checkREAD MORESanthoaha m n santhuCertified Buyer12 Aug, 201681PermalinkReport Abuse
4★By Expert     -Vaishnav VJGood Product by SamsungThe things from this phone is       1. Marshmellow v6.0       2. Front flash with 5mb camera not so good       3. Its design       4. Primary Camera is not so good with 13mb led flash       5. Battery life is also not so good       6. Its size is correct in its design       7. Supports OTG       9. Only 2GB RAM      10. 16GB Internal storage but only 11GB is availiable      11. 4G supports      12. Ultra power saving mode      13. S bike mode      14. Spe...READ MOREVaishnav Certified Buyer17 May, 2016155PermalinkReport Abuse
4★Look is great but camera is a bit slow.I have been using this phone for the past one month. Look is great and also has metal body. So far I have only noticed a bit slowness in the camera while capturing a photo and switching between your photo gallery and camera. Other than that, phone works fine (good battery back-up) - need to see how long it lastsREAD MOREFlipkart CustomerCertified Buyer17 Aug, 201692PermalinkReport Abuse
```

Selenium is slow, so if you don't need it (see Padraic Cunningham answer), I wouldn't use it.

Comment: I am getting only a empty list as follows: `>>> soup.find_all('div', '_3DCdKt')
[]` If possible could you please show the output?