# Python - using the parametes of Flipkart API

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I was trying to get the reviews information using the script given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643390/python-scraping-unable-to-get-required-data-from-flipkart). I was able to get for a single page. Is there any way to get it for multiple pages. The following is the code:

```
import requests

data = {"productId": "MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z", # end of url pid=MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z
        "count": "15",
        "ratings": "ALL",
        "reviewerType:ALL"
        "sortOrder": "MOST_HELPFUL"}

headers = ({"x-user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36 FKUA/website/41/website/Desktop"})
data = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/api/3/product/reviews", params=data, headers=headers).json()
```

I tried changing the parameters as follows:

```
data = {"productId": "MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z", # end of url pid=MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z
        "count": "15",
        "ratings": "ALL",
        "reviewerType:ALL"
        "sortOrder": "MOST_HELPFUL",
        "page": "2"}
```

But I am getting the same previous reviews. I tried to get the URL path using the following command:

```
data.request.path_url
```

and when I tried pasting the obtained URL in the browser its returning an error. **Is there any way to find which parameter is used to iterate the page numbers.** Kindly help. I am new to Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `start` parameter that controls the current page:

```
data = {"productId": "MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z", # end of url pid=MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z
        "count": "15",
        "ratings": "ALL",
        "reviewerType": "ALL"
        "sortOrder": "MOST_HELPFUL",
        "start": "15"}  # page number 2
```

Comment: worked perfectly.. Thanks a lot. I have a small doubt, how did you identify that the parameter is `start`? Could you please let me know, so that I can also understand. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jeril it's just basically an offset from the beginning and can be generalized as "count * page_number" where `page_number` starts from 0. In other words, for the `count=15`, your first page would have start=0, second: start=15, third: start=30 etc..hope that helps.