# How do I get the correct selector from flipkart review page for web scraping?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, selector

The reviews are in the selector with multiple classes  "row _3wYu6I _3BRC7L".
But when scraping, the response does not have the above selector but instead has "row _3wYu6I _1KVtzT" selector.And this selector has empty list.Actually all the classes with values "_3BRC7L" in flipkart page [Flipkart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeAXS.png) are converted into classes with values "_1KVtzT" in response that I get through scraping. [The list of elements that I get when using xpath of the parent class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUhgG.png). How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: would you show up your code? Have you checked if these classes `_3BRC7L`,  `_1KVtzT` are randomly generated values that differ at each page load?

Comment: Yes, you are right, they are being randomly generated values. I rectified my code now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flipkart page generates dynamic content through ajax requests.That is the reason I could not get the correct class selectors. Now, I changed my code as per the instructions of the following answer: [To retrieve data through ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644642/7141351).
It is very helpful and simple for me to do as I am new to scraping and I need not use scrapy or casperjs.

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath you can get the div with a certain class that contains a paragraph that has an `id` that contains the value review.

This selector is a very good start, you can build from here any selector for the review.

```
//div[.//p[contains(@id, 'review')]][@class='col']
```

Comment: I tried giving the xpath. But the problem is that flipkart generates dynamic content nowadays and when scraping, I am not getting  the correct selector used in their html page. So, I retrieved data using ajax requests of their pages.